# Setting a counter to the value of a reference

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I have a use case description, something along the lines of:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item User does X.
    \item User does Y. \label{y}
    \item User does Z. \label{z}
\end{enumerate}
```

Then there is an *alternative* path that deviates from action Y. It is shown in a different list. I would like to start that list with the value of the Y item above (in this case, the second list would start at 2). I tried:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{\ref{y}}\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}
    \item User does Y2.
    \item Continue with Z (\ref{z}).
\end{enumerate}
```

However, this only works when the index has been made already. Otherwise, I get:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You can see the package `refcount` or, more generally, `zref`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `refcount` (as egreg already proposed) in conjunction with the `enumitem` package and its `start=...` feature (no need to use `\setcounter{enumi}{...}` explicitly then.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item User does X.
    \item User does Y. \label{y}
    \item User does Z. \label{z}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[start={\getrefnumber{y}}]
%    \setcounter{enumi}{\ref{y}}\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}
    \item User does Y2.
    \item Continue with Z (\ref{z}).
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

[image]